# Where are .ini files stored in WINE

Tags: wine

I have a DOS and Windows program Ccsc.exe That requires an .ini file Ccsc.ini . Does anyone know where that file should be located so that WINE picks it up just as Windows would picc it up? On windows it is START>ALL PROGRAMS>PIC-C>USER DATA . The INI file tess CCSC where to get the include files. I="C:\ ...

Answer (score 0):

The .ini files are stored in your `.wine`  directory (`~/.wine` or `/home/your_ID/.wine`) under a directory called `windows` (there are many in different folders ).

If you can't find your `.wine` -> That's a hidden directory, you can acces it through your file browser by selecting "View -> Show hidden files".

Hope it helps.